# What container to choose

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, containers

I thought about storing some objects ... and now I don't know what to choose.

So, now I have such code:

```
std::map<std::string, Object*> mObjects;
```

But, as I was told here before, it's slow due to allocation of `std::string` in each searching, so the key should be integer.

Why did I chose `std::string` as key? Because it's very easy to access objects by their name, for example:

```
mObjects["SomeObj"];
```

So my first idea is:

```
std::map<int, Object*> mObjects;
```

and key is an CRC of object name:

```
mObjects[CRC32("SomeObject")];
```

But it's a bit unstable. And I know there is special hash-maps for this.
And the last, I have to sort my objects in map using some `Compare` function.

Any ideas about container I can use?

So again, the main points:

- Accesing objects by string, but keyshould be integer, not string
- Sorting objects in map by some function

*p.s. boost usage is permissible.*

Comment: Did you measure the performance using string keys first before saying it's slow?

Comment: Are strings required due to runtime constraints, or are all the values known at compile time, and could be replaced with a constant, such as: `const int SOME_OBJECT = 1; ... mObject[SOME_OBJECT] ...`

Comment: @thanatos no, they can't. There are near 1000 objects.

Comment: Can you use an `unordered_map`?

Comment: you could also check out `std::hash_map` but I doubt that's what you want ... I would probably accept the relative slowness of string construction in favor of stability and ease of understanding.

Comment: @kennytm unordered can't order objects by some information, right? And I need such functionality. Btw, I can use 2 maps if I need to get that 2 points I choose in post.

Comment: Why do you say that you have to allocate a string for each search? std::map doesn't say anything about copying the keys while doing a search.

You will only allocate (and this isn't slow, man) a string once for each entry on map. And again, if you're looking for performance, you should take on account how much time you take on calculating the CRC (you will calculate a CRC for each search).

Comment: @Ockonal I'm confused, where is search done?

Comment: @Ockonal I'm also confused, sorting a map? Maps are always automatically sorted by key, unordered maps are sorted by internal hash. Maybe you could check MultiIndex container from boost library. You could create container with 2 type of keys - string and integer.

Comment: You could look into Boost.MultiIndex, it allows you to index items in various ways in the same container. You could use a hashed index for fast searches, and an ordered index for sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but are you always accessing items in the map by a literal string? If so, then you should just use consecutive enumerated values with symbolic names, and an appropriately sized `vector`.

Assuming that you won't know the names until runtime 1000 items in the map seems really small for searching to possibly be a bottleneck. Are you *sure* that the lookup is the performance problem? Have you profiled to make sure that is the case? In general, using the most intuitive container is going to result in better code (because you can grasp the algorithm more easily) code.

Does your comment about constructing strings imply that you passing C-strings into the find function over and over? Try to avoid that by using `std::string` consistently in your application.

If you insist on using the two-part approach: I suggest storing all your items in a `vector`. Then you have one `unordered_map` from string to index and another `vector` that has all the indexes into the main container. Then you sort this second container of indexes to get the ordering you need. Finally, when you delete items from the master container you'll need to clean up both of the other two referencing containers.

Comment: What about map. I call search for about ~250 objects each ~11 ms. That's small number? And all of them are iterated each ~11 ms too. I think, that boost::multiindex is what I need.

Comment: Can you post a code that you are using to search/iterate map, because (if I understand numbers correctly) time is very large. Do you build release version of code, sometimes debug version is very slow.

Comment: @Ockonal You aren't using `std::find` on your map are you?